# What is the shape, name if it exists, and length of these curves?

Tags: geometry

We are aware of the problem of four dogs at the corners of a square who simultaneously decide to chase each other at the same speed. Assuming that no two dogs chase each other and that no dog chases the dog furthest away, the paths taken by the dogs form four beautiful logarithmic curves that meet at the center, each with a length equal to that of the side of the square. However assume two dogs go rogue and decide instead to chase the dogs furthest away. How does this affect the lengths and shapes of the four curves? How does this problem change if there are only three dogs at the corners of an equilateral triangle or perhaps five dogs at the vertices of a pentagon?

Answer (score 1):

These are curves of pursuit.

Look it up.